# This form cannot be opened because it requires the domain permission level infopath 2013

Tags: infopath

I create the InfoPath Form and save on my local machine after that I copy this form to another user machine that time I  get the error "this form cannot be opened because it requires the domain permission level ". In this form I set Automatically determine security.[image]

Comment: Is your other machine connected in same network?

Comment: Yes it connected to same network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this:

1. Open `%temp%` folder by typing %temp% in Run.
2. Clear up all the files in the temp folder or delete Temporary
   Internet Files folder.
3. Reopen InfoPath form by Right-click the file and choose `Design`

Comment: Thanks Viraj for reply But I don't want to open the form in design mode i want to open this form in InfoPath Filler so user can fill the form and save the form.

Comment: Open InfoPath - Click "Design this form"  -- then from the menu bar select "Tools," "Form Options," "Security and Trust" - and then UNCHECK "Automatically determine security level (recommended)."
Select Domain/Full Trust option

Comment: Additionally, delete all the files on AppData on the following two locations: `C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\InfoPath` and `C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\InfoPath`

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I need to edit existing form and when I tried to open it, it was giving the same error. After googling it I found that I need to just right click on it and click on design instead of double clicking on it and open it.